# How to thread a QGLWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I have widget:

```
class Main_Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Main_Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Main_Widget();
private:
    MyOGLWidget *mOGL;
    QThread *mThread;
    QPushButton *mStart;
    QPushButton *mStop;
}
```

Then, I created all as following:

```
mOGL = new MyOGLWidget();
mThread = new QThread();
mStart = new QPushButton();
mStop = new QPushButton();
//move to other thread
mOGL->moveToThread(mThread);
```

I want to use animation at the `mOGL`. For this idea, I have a following code:

```
class MyOGLWindow : public QGLWidget
{
   private:
        bool mEnd; //default false

   //...

   public:
        void doLoop()
        {
            while(mEnd)
            {
                //animation
                updateGL();
            }
        }
   public slots:
        void slotStart()
        {
                mEnd = true;
        }
        void slotStop()
        {
                mEnd = false;
        }
}
```

And I do connect my two buttons to `slotStart()`, `slotStop()`. But If I use start button(which causes `slotStart()`), my `Main_Widget` is freezes, but my animation is successfully works. How I can start my infinity loop and not to freeze my `Main_Window`, and how to stop?

Comment: Show the full code, not just chunks of it.

Comment: So far it's obvious what the problems are. +1 for showing code that's actually relevant to the problem :)

Comment: @KubaOber: OPs are supposed to show a self-contained example that can reproduce the problem. The quality requirement has never been less, and hopefully will never be. Strictly speaking, all those new lines could be done for something else than the class members, etc. It is important to see everything as an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) compliant test case. Answers may guess, but they can also be wrong.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I agree that in most cases a self-contained example is the most desired. Here, though, the posted code is actually relevant to the problem. It's rare but pleasant indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The UI, other than the OpenGL view, freezes since you don't return to the event loop. It is an error to move any class that derives from `QWidget`, *including* `QGLWidget`, to another thread.

To do rendering from another thread, you need to move the `QGLContext` (and not `QGLWidget`) to the render thread. Follow the documentation of `QGLWidget` in this respect. The widget's paint event handler must do nothing - since otherwise it would use the GL context from the wrong (GUI) thread. You can use a zero-duration timer in a `QObject` running in the render thread to obviate the need for a custom `end` flag. Whenever the thread's event loop is finished by invoking `QThread::quit()`, the object will stop executing.

You also need to use a thread class that's safe to destruct. Properly designed C++ classes are always destructible. `QThread` is a weirdo - we fix it here.

As a matter of style, it is not necessary to have widget children allocated on the heap. It's a minor waste of heap, in fact, since heap blocks have overhead comparable to the size of a `QObject` instance.

The below shows a sketch of things that need to be addressed for multi-threaded OpenGL in Qt.

```
class Thread : public QThread {
  using QThread::run; // final
public:
  ~QThread() { quit(); wait(); }
};

class ThreadGLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {}
  void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *) { emit resized(size()); }
public:
  explicit ThreadGLWidget(QWidget * parent = 0) : QGLWidget(parent) {
    // Release the context in this thread.
    doneCurrent();
  }
  Q_SIGNAL void resized(QSize);
};

class Animator : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  QBasicTimer mTimer;
  QSize mWidgetSize;
  QPointer<QGLContext> mGLContext;
  void nextFrame() {
    mGLContext.makeCurrent();
    ...
    updateGL();
  }
  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) {
    if (ev->timerId() == mTimer.timerId()) nextFrame();
  }
public:
  explicit Animator(QGLContext * ctx, QObject * parent = 0) :
    QObject(parent), mGLContext(ctx)
  { 
    // The use of the timer obviates the custom stop flag. Our
    // thread's event loop is not blocked and is quittable.
    mTimer.start(0, this);
  }
  Q_SLOT void setSize(QSize size) { mWidgetSize = size; }
};

class Main_Widget : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Main_Widget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent),
    mLayout(this), mStart("Start"), mStop("Stop"),
    mAnimator(mOGL.context())
  {
    mLayout.addWidget(&mOGL, 0, 0, 1, 2);
    mLayout.addWidget(&mOGL, 1, 0);
    mLayout.addWidget(&mOGL, 1, 1);
    mAnimator.setSize(mOGL.size());
    mOGL.context()->moveToThread(&mThread);
    mAnimator.moveToThread(&mThread);
    mAnimator.connect(&mOGL, SIGNAL(resized(QSize)), SLOT(setSize(QSize)));
    mThread.start();
  }
private:
  QGridLayout mLayout;
  ThreadGLWidget mOGL;
  QPushButton mStart;
  QPushButton mStop;
  Animator mAnimator; // must be declared before its thread and after the GL widget
  QThread mThread;
  // Destruction order of GL-related objects:
  // 1. mThread - stops the animation, makes the animator and context threadless
  // 2. mAnimator - now threadless, can be destructed from our thread
  // 3. mOGL - its context is threadless and can be destructed from our thread
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the `using QThread::run; // final` line is necessary.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Because if you reimplement `run`, you're likely not to run an event loop in it, and then the `quit` method becomes a no-op, and the destructor can't quit the running operation, and the class really doesn't work anymore. It only makes sense with `run` being final. This class is not meant to be derived from. Other `QThread` reimplementations will have their own way of quitting things, of course, but they shouldn't derive from `Thread`.

Comment: 1) There is Q_DECL_FINAL. 2) More importantly, why would you derive from it in the context of this question? It would be more comprehensive without it.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to handle animation on a `QGLWidget` is to **use a `QTimer`, not a `QThread`**!

Overwrite `QGLWidget`'s initialization method, `initializeGL()`, to start the timer. You can use something like this, which calls `_tick()` every 33ms:

```
 QTimer::singleShot(33, this, SLOT(_tick()));
```

I just want to clarify that [`singleShot()`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtimer.html#singleShot) is a static method of `QTimer`, which fires only once. That means that when `_tick()` (*private slot*) is called, it should do a few things:

1. Update all the variables that control animation (rotation, movement, speed, etc);
2. Trigger `paintGL()` indirectly, by calling `updateGL()`;
3. Start a new singleShot timer.

   ```
   void GLWidget::_tick()
   {
       /* 1- Update state variables */

       /* 2- Call paintGL() indirectly to do the drawing */
       updateGL(); 

       /* 3- Set a new singleShot timer to invoke this method again, 33ms from now */
       QTimer::singleShot(33, this, SLOT(_tick()));
   }
   ```

That's how you should handle animation with `QGLWidget`.

Answer (score -1):

All GUI operations must run in one thread.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread

> ***GUI Thread and Worker Thread***
>
> As mentioned, each program has one thread when it is started. This
>   thread is called the "main thread" (also known as the "GUI thread" in
>   Qt applications). The Qt GUI must run in this thread. All widgets and
>   several related classes, for example QPixmap, don't work in secondary
>   threads. A secondary thread is commonly referred to as a "worker
>   thread" because it is used to offload processing work from the main
>   thread.

This is also true in Qt 5,

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread

Comment: While true, it's not helpful, since the OpenGL context can definitely be accessed from any one thread at a time. It doesn't provide a solution to the asker's problem.

Comment: @KubaOber: it is useful what the answer writes, and it is also a quote from the corresponding Qt documentation. Please be more respectful and thankul towards people who are trying to help.

Comment: Just because it's in the documentation, doesn't mean that it's helpful. In fact, the documentation is slightly deceptive, since OpenGL is for GUI use, but it can run in a separate thread. It is also possible to do rendering onto a QImage on a worker thread, and then draw that image in the GUI thread. On modern platforms the `drawImage` can be much faster than other complex drawing, and it's a valid method of doing multithreaded rendering, for example. So I maintain my view that this answer is unhelpful.

Comment: QImage is not a QWidget, and it is not mentioned in the documentation either. The OP had issues with moving the opengl widget to a different thread, and the documentation here explains why: `All widgets and several related classes, for example QPixmap, don't work in secondary threads.`.